# Order $n$ automorphism of $\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{F}$ has every $n$-th root of unity as eigenvalue.

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory

I was reading [these](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/111101001/downloads/Lecture19.pdf) notes and came across the following result:
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field containing a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta.$ Suppose that $\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{F}$ is a cyclic Galois extension of degree $n$ with $G := \Gal(\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{F}) = \langle \sigma\rangle.$ Then, $\zeta$ is an eigenvalue of the $\mathbb{F}$-linear map $\sigma.$

From the proof, it seemed that we don't really need all the hypothesis used. I was wondering if the following statement is true.

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field containing an $n$-th root of unity $\zeta.$ Suppose that $\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{F}$ is *any* finite extension and $\sigma : \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{E}$ is an $\mathbb{F}$-automorphism of order $n.$ Then, $\zeta$ is an eigenvalue of the $\mathbb{F}$-linear map $\sigma.$

In the above, I have dropped the hypothesis that $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity and that $\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{F}$ is a Galois extension. Moreover, I am not even assuming that the degree of the extension is the same $n$.
I am assuming finite extension only because I use results about minimal polynomials, which I have only seen in the context of finite-dimensional vector spaces.
By order of $\sigma$, I mean its order in the group of all $\mathbb{F}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{E}$.

Here is (what I think is) a proof:

*Proof.* Note that the operator $\sigma$ satisfies $T^n - 1 \in \mathbb{F}[T]$.
We claim that it is the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$. Indeed, if $\sigma$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $m < n,$ then the distinct functions $\sigma, \ldots, \sigma^m$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{F}$ and hence, over $\mathbb{E}$.

However, we can view $\sigma, \ldots, \sigma^m$ as distinct characters of $\mathbb{E}^\times$ in $\mathbb{E}.$ Thus, we have contradicted the fact that distinct group characters are linearly independent.

Thus, $T^n - 1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$ and thus, its roots in $\mathbb{F}$ are eigenvalues of $\sigma$. In particular, so is $\zeta$. $\hspace{2cm} \Box$

---

Is the proof correct? Is there some place where I do need the additional hypothesis?

Comment: You want to prove that $\zeta$ has an eigenvector in $E$, that's the interesting result, under the first hypothesis it will give $E=F(a^{1/n})$.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, in the proposition right after, I see that all the assumptions are required. However, for this preliminary lemma, the hypothesis I've given suffices too, right? I have not explicitly constructed an eigenvector in $\Bbb E$ but used the result about minimal polynomials, from linear algebra.

Comment: It looks correct to me.